# How to Open a Specific View Controller On didReceiveRemoteNotification when application is in back ground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am implementing a alarm where i am getting pushNotification from server, i am receiving perfect push notification and it is working fine in foreground mode but when application enter in background then it getting only push notification but not loading the view which i want to load

Please check the Code Below

```
func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
        forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}
```

This method calling from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    if notificationSettings.types != .None {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(tokenString, forKey: "deviceToken")
}
```

This is the final method

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        print(userInfo)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AlarmDetailsController") as! AlarmDetailsController
        //let dVC:AlarmDetailsController = navigationController.topViewController as! AlarmDetailsController
        navigationController.isPushNotification = true
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: {})        
}
```

Please help me for that problem **Remember My Application is working fine in foreground mode**

Comment: If it is in background, save that you have to open the viewController, once the user opens the app. Check in the saved position and open required VC.

Comment: @New16 Exactly the same thing what was wanted, **But** when i received a push notification i want that my device should play a sound which is plying by `PlaySound()` method which is in ViewDidLoad() method of `AlarmDetailsController` Controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.Firstly you should Turn On Background Fetch in app "Capabilities"
2. Then use following code in app delegate

In AppDelegate class add following code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
       // print(userInfo)
let vc = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "destinationVC") as! destinationVC
                            self.visibleNavController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

For iOS 10 use following code:
1.Import

```
 import UserNotifications
```

For foreground fetch

```
     @available(iOS 10.0, *)
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (_ options: UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            var userInfo = NSDictionary()
            userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary
            let pay = userInfo as NSDictionary
   let driverLocationVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "destinationVC") as! destinationVC
                                self.visibleNavController.pushViewController(driverLocationVC, animated: true)


    }
```

For the background

```
 @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")


        var userInfo = NSDictionary()
        userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary
        print(userInfo)
    let driverLocationVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DriverLocationVC") as! DriverLocationVC
                            self.visibleNavController.pushViewController(driverLocationVC, animated: true)
}
```

For device token fetch

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
        print("Got token data! \(tokenString)")

        UserDefaults.standard.set(tokenString, forKey: "device_token")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
```

Comment: hmm Intersting let my try this code i have already open `Background Fetch`

Comment: i did try your solution it's not playing alarm tone which is in `playSound()` method

Comment: i had implement it by your previous answer

Comment: @Pushpendra You have to play your own custom mp3 file using AVFoundation.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'visibleNavController'. Could you please help?

Comment: visibleNavController is application specific UINavigationViewCotroller which store viewcontrollers. You can use as per your application usecase.

Answer (score 1):

If you app is suspended check the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` in the dictionary from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    ...

    // Check if launched from notification
    if let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [String: AnyObject] {

        // handle your notification like in application:didReceiveRemoteNotificatioUserInfo:
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this easy and shortcut way thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

**First you need to set like this in your Xcode**

[image]

There are three states : **Foreground,Background,Killed** which you need to know clear details about your notification.

***1.* Foreground** : As soon as your notification come in when your app is at foreground, it will lead to the specific screen when you tapped at banner or alert base on your configuration in normal mode. But,at background modes, it can even do silently navigate as soon as your notification arrive without tapping it.

***2.* Background** : If your app is not at foreground,using background mode can help you open the specific screen if you handle it inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and as soon as the app is open when you tapped it,it will lead to it's specific screen.

***3.* Killed** : If your app is not in memory, only tapping push notification work for navigating specific screen because it wasn't in device memory so `didReceiveRemoteNotification` will not trigger if user neglect the notification.

So,how do we handle the specific screen navigation? That's base on how you develop your application design and I can't provide correct answer until I see your code.

But,yeah you can navigate to specific when the app is in background as soon as you open the app by tapping notification which appear on banner or lock screen.Everything can be done inside your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` under one condition when you want to do it in background.

Take a look at this :

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

At your push notification json,you have to include the following

```
content-available : 1
```

when that is included,it can do background execution even the app is in background base on the additional data which you send from the server.

At your additional data :

```
{apns : [],
data : [
   "Navigate" : "Home"
   ]}
```

Then at your `didReceiveRemoteNotification`,

```
if let aps = userInfo["data"] as? NSDictionary{
      // get the "Home" data and do navigation here
      // You might need to instantiate storyboard of the specific view controller which you want to go as RootViewController
}
```

So, when your notification comes,it will lead to specific screen in background if you do as soon as you tap the push notification from banner or alert.The application gonna open and it will lead to specific screen.

Comment: Lovely Answer Thanks

Comment: Welcome m8, hope it help you.

Comment: yes it's very OSM, but i had implement first answer given by @dhruv_singh 
But theoretical it's very helpful for me

Comment: Don't forget to add "content-available = 1" if u want to trigger background process unless it will do nothing. If you use other third party services,they might do it automatically for you. But, for firebase and parse, it's has to do like that from my experience.

Comment: Yes I did and Now It's working as i want, Thanks for your focus on my Question

Comment: Anytime,Cheers m8