# Write to Plist when receiving push notification and app is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I'm using application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:. In this method I call the writeToFile function in order to write to a plist-file. This works fine when the app is open or in background. It does not work when the app is closed (when terminated with app swiping up).

Should this be possible?

Comment: You have to check the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`  in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40990702/1390857

Comment: @ThomasG. But it will work only if the app is opened via notification.

Comment: "Should this be possible?" No, if your app is terminated it is not launched when a push arrives.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in iOS 10 by setting the mutable-content = 1 in your notification payload and implement notification service extension. More info about UINotificationServiceExtension: https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension

But this works on iOS 10 and above only. There is no way to check for iOS 10 below devices.

Comment: Thanks, there is no way to writeToFile without the need of tapping the notification?

Comment: In iOS 10 if the mutable content is 1, then your extension your will always be called so you can do the desired tasks. It will work without clicking the notification. But below iOS 10, it's not possible.

Comment: Its not going to be as easy as implied here. The extension and the containing app cannot directly communicate and files are sandboxed (meaning the extension can't access its apps' files and the app can't access the extension's files). You would have to set up a shared group so that both the extension and the app have a common area where data can be written to and read from.

Comment: Yes, app groups needs to be enabled on the project. But this takes 10 mins to enable. So what's the difficulty?